# Android IntentService slowing down UI Thread

Tags: java, android, performance, service, p2p

My IntentService is raising the **"Skipped XX frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."** message in  the LogCat, but I don't understand why.

I'm working on an app that communicates with a P2P broker. I decided to move all the communication logic to a Service. Initially I was doing something in that fashion:

```
class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    onCreate() {
        // This info need to stay up as long as the context is
        stablishEndpointAndTransport();
    }

    @Override
    onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId) {
        registerAccountId(intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ACCOUNT_ID));
    }

    @Override
    IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    onDestroy() {
        if (registeredAccount) deleteAccount();
        deleteTransportAndEndpoint();
    }
}
```

It ran OK even though I didn't create a worker thread to handle all that logic. But as I will need to implement more connectivity logic, I decided to move the logic to an IntentService, since it handles everything on a background worker thread.

All I did was rename the base class to `IntentService`, move the content in the `onStartCommand()` method to the `onHandleIntent()`, specify an action constant to that specific case and erase `onStartCommand()` and `onBind()` overrides.

How can that change impact the performance of the main thread?

**EDIT**

Might be related, but both `stablishEndpointAndTransport()` and `registerAccountId()` run some methods from a framework that are *asynchronous*. Specifically, the methods that communicate to the broker are. That being said, I might give up on `IntentService` because the hardwork is already ran on a different thread (Explainig why it actually runs fine as a `Service`). Still, I don't get why `IntentService` is making UI Thread skip frames.

Comment: THis isn't an IntentService.  IntentServices extend from IntentService.  This is a normal Service, and does its work on the UI thread.

Comment: This is the `Service` that i've turned into `IntentService`. The differences are described under the code snippet. That's literally only that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. Given that I was making async calls, i was returning from the `onHandleIntent` method before the calls would finish. The problem is that `stopSelf(int)` is called once it returns, as it's implemented by the `ServiceHandler`:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    onHandleIntent((Intent)msg.obj);
    stopSelf(msg.arg1);
}
```

`IntentService` was not designed to perform the task I was intending. To my scenario, I reimplemented it as `BackgroundService` and erased `stopSelf()` along with other modifications to keep the `BackgroundService` thread active as long as possible ([see this gist](https://gist.github.com/gfreivasc/e7a7d263eb9c6db554160af7c94cbac7)).

Comment: You don't have an intent service. The code you posted is extending `Service`

Comment: @Voski The second paragraph after the snippet in the question explains what I did

Answer (score 1):

> Android IntentService slowing down UI Thread

No way, As you know IntentService creates a worker thread and uses that thread to run the service. So the problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: Indeed, makes no sense to me, but the modifications described are the ones that cause the problem. I've even rewritten the `IntentService` back to `Service` and the message was gone (and the behavior right)